# How to filter Chrome Dev Tool Network calls by Request url?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I wish to filter all the network calls having value / sub-string `valueresearchonline.com` against `Request URL` in Headers, how to do that ?

I tried `domain: valueresearchonline.com` in the filter box but it doesn't work

Comment: Use `url:` prefix without a space. You can also just enter `valueresearchonline.com` as it will filter the URL by default.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct way to filter the network calls by their request URL however, you need to remove the space between the property and it's value:

```
domain:valueresearchonline.com
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me below solution worked

Step 1:

type `domain:` and wait for few seconds; Chrome will show you the list of domains.

[image]

Step 2:

Then enter `domain:*.domain:*.valueresearchonline.com`